# TypeError: a is null

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm using the following jQuery Ajax call... anyhow it's not working.

Error:`TypeError: a is null`

Here is my Code:

```
var prefixUrl = "autocomplete?action=complete&id=";
$('#complete-field').bind('keyup', function(){
var url =  prefixUrl + escape($('#complete-field').val());
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    getUrl:url,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(responseXML) {
        var composers = responseXML.getElementsByTagName("composers")[0];
        if (composers.childNodes.length > 0) {

            $('#complete-table').css("border", "1px solid green");
            $('#complete-table').css("margin", "128px 0 0 -82px");

            for (var loop = 0; loop < composers.childNodes.length; loop++) {
                var composer = composers.childNodes[loop];
                var firstName = composer.getElementsByTagName("firstName")[0];
                var lastName = composer.getElementsByTagName("lastName")[0];
                var composerId = composer.getElementsByTagName("id")[0];

                appendComposer(firstName.childNodes[0].nodeValue, lastName.childNodes[0].nodeValue, composerId.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }
        }
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('xhr.status: ' + xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
  });
});
```

Any Idea please?

Many Thanks

Comment: Um, which line are you getting that error on?

Comment: don't see any error here, must be somewhere else in your code ... usually firebig gives the line of the error ... so you know where it happens

Comment: Am I blind, or there isn't even a variable called `a` in this snippet?

Comment: @Alvaro I'm sure a is buried deep in some obfuscated jQuery code.  But at least knowing the line where the error occurs would be helpful.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I wouldn't be surprised if `a` refers to the (missing, but necessary) `url` attribute of the jQuery.ajax options hash. In fact, I'm willing to bet some SO points on it!

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    getUrl:url,
    ...
```

should be

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    ...
```

See the docs at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You'd think that something as heavily-developed as jQuery would give meaningful error messages if you forget to specify a required parameter...

Comment: @Kolink I agree with you, but on the other hand, jQuery does provide unminified code for development and testing.